# Creating PDF using C#

Tags: c#, pdf

When I try to convert binary file to PDF the pdf has damaged.

```
byte[] stream = presenter.getItemTable();

Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader ("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=PressRelease.pdf");
Response.BinaryWrite(stream);//Entities.EDRSearchResult.ByteStream);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

However when I convert same binary to Excel it is working fine and can open without any error.

```
byte[] stream = presenter.getItemTable();
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats - officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachment;filename=DataTable.xls");
Response.BinaryWrite(stream);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Please help me.

Comment: This probably isn't it but you should always wrap streams in `using` blocks. Try something like `using (var stream = presenter.getItemTable()) {...}`

Comment: Please indicate where you **convert** your data. All I see you doing is setting a header **claiming** a format.

Answer (score 0):

when you try to convert binary file to PDF in this case you write

```
  Response.AddHeader ("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=PressRelease.pdf");
```

Try

```
  Response.AddHeader ("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=PressRelease.pdf");
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response however still same result.

Comment: https://xamltopdf.codeplex.com/                                                                                    maybe Response.BinaryWrite(stream); change to Response.OutputStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#Prefix_vnd application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet                                                                                     instead of                                                            application/vnd.openxmlformats - officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet